# How can I disable usb autosuspend for a given particular device or all usb

Tags: fedora, usb, powertop

I am using on Fedora 32 a wireless usb mouse that get autosupended and that's driving me crazy.
I looked online and tried many things without success.

I identified the device using powertop

```
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb1]
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb2]
   Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-7 (8087:0a2b)
   Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-9 (138a:0097)
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device USB3.0-CRW [Generic]                                                        
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device Integrated Camera [SunplusIT Inc]
>> Bad           Autosuspend for USB device 2.4G Wireless Receiver [Nordic]
```

I tried many things

- tried to install `tuned`
- added a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` by doing `sudo echo "options usbcore autosuspend=-1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-usb-autosuspend.conf > /dev/null`
- updated `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-113d6727-daed-4f2f-b1e7-5ejsudt456370 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet usbcore.autosuspend=-1"`

That did nothing
I would like to selectively disable autosuspend for that mouse **OR** disable usb autosuspend on everything

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by creating a crontab as root

```
@reboot echo 'on' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/control';
```

that was what was given by powertop when I was toggling on/off

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar (on Ubuntu instead of Fedora). Adding a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` also didn't work for me, but running `sudo update-grub` after updating `/etc/default/grub` did work for me.